# Differentiation under the integral sign - line integral?

Tags: integration, fluid-dynamics

In the proof of [Kelvin's circulation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin's_circulation_theorem) it is common to do the following manipulation:
$$\newcommand{\p}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{ #1}{ #2}} \newcommand{\l}[0]{\left(} \newcommand{\r}[0]{\right)} 
\f{D \Gamma}{Dt}=\f{D}{Dt} \oint_{C(t)} \vec u \cdot d\vec x$$
$$=\oint_{c(t)} \f{D\vec u}{Dt}\cdot d\vec x+\oint_{c(t)}\vec u\cdot d\l \f{D\vec x}{Dt}\r$$
I am uneasy about the validity of this expression. Please can someone explain the logic and maths behind it.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes non-rigorous derivations in physics are both expedient and illuminating, but this is definitely not the case with the linked "proof" of Kelvin's theorem.

First you can dispense with the outer material derivative and replace it with an ordinary derivative with respect to $t$.  The circulation around a closed material curve $C(t)$ -- one that is convected with the flow and contains the same fluid particles -- has no explicit dependence on the spatial coordinates. Hence,

$$\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial t}+ \mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla\Gamma = \frac{D\Gamma}{Dt} = \frac{d\Gamma}{dt}.$$

Consider the one-dimensional analog

$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + u\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\int_a^{C(t)} u(x',t)\, dx' = \frac{d}{dt}\int_a^{C(t)} u(x',t)\, dx',$$

Assuming all functions are sufficiently smooth we can apply Leibniz's rule to obtain

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^{C(t)} u(x',t)\, dx' = \int_a^{C(t)} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x',t)\, dx' + u(C(t),t) C'(t).$$

This gives you a hint that you cannot merely interchange the derivative and the integral and that some type of "boundary term" is going to appear.

In the Lagrangian description of fluid flow there is a family of smooth maps

$$\mathbf{\xi}(\cdot,t) : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$$

for which a fluid particle located at $\mathbf{x}_0$ at time $t =0$ is located at $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{\xi}(\mathbf{x}_0,t)$ at time $t$. We obtain the Eulerian velocity field according to $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},t) = \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{\xi}(\mathbf{x}_0,t),t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf{\xi}( \mathbf{x}_0,t) = \mathbf{\xi}_t( \mathbf{x}_0,t).$

At time $t$, the closed material curve $C(t)$ can be parametrized as $C(t) = \{\mathbf{x}(s,t) : 0 \leqslant s \leqslant 1\}$ and is the image of a curve $C(0)$ under the map $\mathbb{\xi}(\cdot,t) : \mathbf{x}_0(s) \mapsto \mathbf{x}(s,t).$

The circulation is given by

$$\Gamma(t) = \oint_{C(t)} \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},t) \cdot d \mathbf{x}= \int_0^1 \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}(s,t),t) \cdot \frac{\partial}{ \partial s} \mathbf{x}(s,t)\,ds.$$

With a change of variable $\mathbb{x} = \mathbb{\xi}(\mathbb{x}_0,t),$ we can express the circulation as

$$\Gamma(t) = \int_0^1 \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{\xi}(\mathbf{x}_0(s),t),t) \cdot \frac{\partial }{ \partial s} \mathbf{\xi}(\mathbf{x}_0(s),t)\,ds.$$

Now assuming the integrand is sufficiently smooth, we can take the derivative with respect to $t$ under the integral sign and split into two integrals to obtain

$$\frac{d\Gamma}{dt} = \int_0^1 \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{\xi}(\mathbf{x}_0(s),t),t) + \nabla \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{\xi}(\mathbf{x}_0(s),t),t) \cdot \mathbf{\xi}_t( \mathbf{x}_0(s),t)\right] \cdot \frac{\partial}{ \partial s} \mathbf{\xi}(\mathbf{x}_0(s),t)\,ds \\ + \int_0^1 \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{\xi}(\mathbf{x}_0(s),t),t) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{ \partial s} \mathbf{\xi}(\mathbf{x}_0(s),t)\,ds.$$

Reversing the change of variables and interchanging the $t-$ and $s-$derivatives in the second integral we get

$$\frac{d\Gamma}{dt} = \oint_{C(t)} \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},t) + \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},t) \cdot \nabla \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},t) \right] \cdot d \mathbf{x} + \int_0^1 \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{\xi}(\mathbf{x}_0(s),t),t) \cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial s} \mathbf{\xi}_t(\mathbf{x}_0(s),t)\,ds \\ = \oint_{C(t)} \frac{D\mathbf{u}}{Dt}\cdot d \mathbf{x} + \int_0^1 \mathbf{u}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}(s,t),t)\,ds .$$

I prefer to leave the second integral in this comprehensible parametric form rather than introduce the cryptic notation

$$\oint_{C(t)} \mathbf{u} \cdot d \left(\frac{D\mathbf{x}}{Dt}\right)$$

Comment: Great post. For the conditions given in Kelvins Theorem, the last integral $\int_0^1 \mathbf{u}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}(s,t),t)\,ds$ should be zero. How can one show this with the present formalism? In other more non-rigorous sources this turns into a gradient of some scalar function and then one employs stokes theorem and since the curl of gradient is identically zero the integral disappears. But I cannot quite see how here.

Comment: @DiggingDeep: Thank you.  I have not looked at this for a while, but I see what you are asking.  I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: Note that $ \int_0^1 \mathbf{u}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}(s,t),t)\, ds = \int_0^1\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}|\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}(s,t),t)|^2\, ds = \frac{1}{2}\left(\left.|\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}(s,t),t)|^2\right|_{s=1}-  \left.|\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}(s,t),t)|^2\right|_{s=0}\right) = 0$ since for the parameterization of the closed contour $C(t)$ we have $\mathbf{x}(s=1,t) = \mathbf{x}(s=0,t)$.

Comment: Wow, that is so transparent now, thanks a lot for taking the time to revive such an old post. I really think the wiki-page for Kelvins theorem should be updated with a procedure along your answer, with clear 1D integrals rather than the cryptic material derivative of a differential.