# How do I differentiate under the line integral along an open curve?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Is there a way to perform the following differentiation under the line integral sign ?

$$ I = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{\Gamma\left(t\right)}\vec{u}\cdot d\vec{x}\right) $$

provided the vector $ \vec{u}=\vec{u}\left(\vec{x},t\right)$  varies in space and also varies with the variable $ t $. And provided that $ \vec{u} $ may not be conservative.

The curve $\Gamma$ may also be allowed to depend on the variable $ t $ and may even be allowed to undergo translations and rotations. But, the most important thing about $\Gamma$ is that it be an **open** curve and not a closed one. This is because I know that the closed curve would be a special case of the 2-D Liebnitz rule.

Is there a general formula for this operation ? and, if so, how could one prove it?

Comment: Covered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2050950/148510) in the fluid dynamical context when $\Gamma(t)$ is a material curve.

Comment: @RRL Looks like a nice post!

Answer (score 0):

This can be quite an uncomfortable thing to encounter the first time. There are a number of rules for this operation depending on the situation or how many dimensions you are working in. One of the rules which may be fitting is called the **Reynolds transport theorem** (seen as you've tagged fluid mechanics, I assume you mean this theorem) which is the same form as the integral you have above. This rule and more can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Post your progress and see if I or others can help further!

I should also mention some examples [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf). As you will see, it is a very powerful method. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If the curve $\Gamma\left(t\right)$ is open then in 2-D, for example, the line integral may be written simply as a sum of two definite integrals.

$$L = \int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}\left(t\right)}u_{x} dx+\int_{y_{0}}^{y_{1}\left(t\right)}u_{y} dy$$

If the initial point $(x_{0},y_{0})$ is fixed, the Leibniz integral rule requires that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Gamma}\vec{u}.(dx,dy)=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}\left(t\right)}u_{x} dx+\frac{d}{dt}\int_{y_{0}}^{y_{1}\left(t\right)}u_{y} dy\\
=\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}\left(t\right)}\frac{\partial u_{x}}{\partial t} dx+\int_{y_{0}}^{y_{1}\left(t\right)}\frac{\partial u_{y}}{\partial t}  dy+ u_{x}\left(x_{1}\left(t\right),t\right)\frac{dx_{1}}{dt}+u_{y}\left(y_{1}\left(t\right),t\right)\frac{dy_{1}}{dt}$$

This then simplifies to

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Gamma\left(t\right)}\vec{u}\cdot d\vec{x}=\int_{\Gamma\left(t\right)}\frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial t}\cdot d\vec{x} +\vec{u}\left(\vec{x_{\Gamma}},t\right)\cdot \frac{d \vec{x_{\Gamma}}}{dt} $$

where I have defined $\vec{x_{\Gamma}}$ to the the end point on $\Gamma$.

under the same assumptions, is this equation true in 3-D?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible to consider the problem i a much more general form.

If the vector $\vec{v_{n}}$ is the normal velocity field of all points along the curve $\Gamma$ and if the vector $\vec{v_{t}}$ is the tangent velocity field along the curve $\Gamma$, then [this](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~kuester/ucb_emlab_sr060.pdf) argument concludes that the derivative under the line integral should be

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Gamma\left(t\right)}\vec{u}\cdot d\vec{x}=\left[\vec{u}\left(\vec{x_{2}},t\right)\cdot \vec{v_{t_2}} -\vec{u}\left(\vec{x_{1}},t\right)\cdot \vec{v_{t_1}}\right]+\int_{\Gamma\left(t\right)}\left[\frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial t}+\left(\vec{v_{n}}\cdot\nabla\right)\vec{u}\right]\cdot d\vec{x} $$
$$+\int_{\Gamma\left(t\right)}\vec{u}\cdot\frac{\partial \vec{v_{n}}}{\partial l}dl$$

where $\vec{x_{1}}$ and $\vec{x_{2}}$ are the coordinates of the initial and final points on $\Gamma$ respectively, while $\vec{v_{t_1}}$ and $\vec{v_{t_2}}$ are the corresponding tangential velocity components. The length along the curve $\Gamma$ i denoted by $l$.