# Differentiating under the integral sign in Kelvin's theorem

Tags: derivatives, fluid-dynamics

I know well that this has already been asked here:

[Differentiation under the integral sign - line integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050950/differentiation-under-the-integral-sign-line-integral)

..but the answer given there already assumes that the length of the contour does not depend on time.. which is the actual point of the question. So I'll rewrite here the problem.

Suppose you have an ideal isoentropic fluid, and consider the circulation on a contour $C(t)$ evolving in time
$$\Gamma(t) =  \oint_{C(t)}\textbf{v}(\textbf{x}(s,t),t)\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\textbf{x}(s,t)ds.$$

Kelvin's Theorem proves $\Gamma$ to be constant in time. But its time derivative is
$$ \frac{d\Gamma}{dt} = \oint_{C(t)}\frac{d\textbf{v}}{dt}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\textbf{x}(s,t)ds + \oint_{C(t)}\textbf{v}\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\textbf{x}ds + BTs,$$

where I denoted with $BTs$ the boundary terms.

Now, the issue is that, according to my textbook, and to the aforementioned answer (and to the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%27s_circulation_theorem as well), these boundary terms are vanishing.

So..why is that?

Shouldn't the length of the line on which we take the circulation depend on time?

Comment: The "answer given there" assumes that the contour is a material curve which is convected with the fluid and so depends upon time.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't the domain of integration be $0 \leq s \leq l_C(t)$ (with $l_C(t)$ being the length of $C(t)$ at time t) instead of $0\leq s \leq1$?

Comment: The variable $s$ is just a parameter used to specify the contour according to $C(t) = \{\mathbf{x}(s,t) : 0 \leqslant s \leqslant 1\}$.  Since it is a closed contour we have $\mathbf{x}(0,t) = \mathbf{x}(1,t)$ which is some arbitrary reference point.  Every point on that contour is moving in time.   As it evolves it could be changing its length.

Comment: If $s$ is a generic parameter, then you're allowed to make it represent a curvilinear abscissa. But in this case, the domain of integration necessarily goes from 0 to the length of the contour, which (in general) depends on time. Thus, boundary terms should appear. 
Speaking of that.. you wrote in your answer that we can take the derivative under the sign of integral just because the integrand is sufficiently smooth. But in general, in order to derive under the sign of integral, it is also needed that the domain of integration does not depend on time. Otherwise, you get additional terms.

Comment: The integral under which I am differentiating after a number of steps has been transformed so that the integration is over a finite interval $[0,1]$.  This is the same approach taken in proving the Reynolds Transport Theorem.  If you are so convinced that all of this (book, article, my answer, the Reynolds Transport proof) is wrong, please elaborate.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound rude..sorry for that. I'll check another book to get a better understanding of that change of coordinates.

Comment: No problem.  I'm trying to understand your concern.  Let me think about it some more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see that the approach in [Differentiation under the integral sign - line integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050950/differentiation-under-the-integral-sign-line-integral) is valid, we can consider the one-dimensional case.

If $f$ is sufficiently smooth, then using the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) we get

$$\tag{1}\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^{C(t)}f(x,t ) \, dx =  \int_0^{C(t)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t ) \, dx + f(C(t),t) C'(t)$$

Using the approach in question, we make the change of variables $x = C(t)s$ where $0 \leqslant s \leqslant 1$ and the integral becomes

$$\tag{2}\int_0^{C(t)}f(x,t ) \, dx = C(t)\int_0^1f(C(t)s,t) \, ds$$

Differentiating with respect to $t$, we get

$$\tag{3}\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^{C(t)}f(x,t ) \, dx= \underbrace{C(t) \frac{d}{dt} \int_0^1 f(C(t)s,t) \, ds}_{A(t)}+ \underbrace{C'(t)  \int_0^1 f(C(t)s,t) \, ds}_{B(t)}  $$

Using (2), the second term $B(t)$ is

$$\tag{4} B(t) = \frac{C'(t)}{C(t)}  C(t)\int_0^1 f(C(t)s,t) \, ds= \frac{C'(t)}{C(t)}  \int_0^{C(t)} f(x,t) \, dx$$

In the first term $A(t)$, we can pass the derivative under the integral to obtain

$$\tag{5}A(t) = C(t) \int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(C(t)s,t) \, ds + C(t) \int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (C(t)s,t)C'(t) s \, ds \\= \int_0^{C(t)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) \, dx + \frac{C'(t)}{C(t)}\int_0^{C(t)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x,t) x \, dx$$

Integrating the second integral by parts, we get

$$\int_0^{C(t)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} f(x,t) x \, dx = \left. xf(x,t)\right|_0^{C(t)}- \int_0^{C(t)} f(x,t) \, dx = C(t)f(C(t),t) - \int_0^{C(t)} f(x,t) \, dx$$

and substitution into (5) yields

$$\tag{6}A(t) = \int_0^{C(t)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) \, dx + f(C(t),t) C'(t) - \frac{C'(t)}{C(t)} \int_0^{C(t)}f(x,t) \, dx$$

Finally, substituting into (3) with (4) an (6), we obtain

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^{C(t)}f(x,t ) \, dx =  \int_0^{C(t)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t ) \, dx + f(C(t),t) C'(t)$$

This matches the result (1) obtained with the Leibniz integral rule and demonstrates the validity of the change of variables approach.

Comment: For the multivariate problem, the boundary term is $\oint_{C(t)}\textbf{v}\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\textbf{x}ds$.  There are no others.  Analogously in the 1-D case, the second integral on the RHS of (5) and the RHS of (4) are the boundary terms -- they reduce to the expected $f(C(t),t)C'(t)$.